# same picture, but different resolution on the same smartphone

Tags: android, html, css, image, jquery-mobile

I have a problem with the resolution of an image in an app that i'm developing for android. in a few words on a page the image is hard to see, and in another you can see well. css and html are the same for both images, and for this reason I can not explain how it is possible. I attach pictures to help you understand, the screenshots are taken from a samsung galaxy s3!

[image: as you see the timer is hard to see in this photo]

[image: but in this photo you can clearly see]

this is the meta:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, target-densityDpi=device-dpi;" />
```

EDIT:
I noticed that the problem occurs when inside the data-role = "content" there is a "ul". I tried to remove the "ul" from the page where there is an image with poor resolution and in fact the problem goes away...

code list:

```
 var link_markup ='<li id="list1"><a onclick="rowSelectedCardio()" href="#" class="ui-link-inherit"><p style="white-space: normal">'+stringCardio+'</p></a><span><img src="img/'+color+'"></span></li>';

$(link_markup).appendTo('#listaCardio');
```

and css:

```
 .scrollable {

   overflow-y: scroll;
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }

.classListCardio li {
    background:#9D9D9C;
    max-height:45px;
    height:45px;
    margin-bottom:0px !important;
    padding:0px !important;
    border-bottom-width:1px;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    }

.classListCardio img {
margin-top:17px !important;
height:11px !important;
width:7px !important;
}

.classListCardio li a {
height:35px !important;
width:95% !important;
float:left;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to tell which phone do you have ??? :-p

Comment: have you checked the meta tag viewport to see if the pixel density is different?

Comment: @PAPAFRESH I edited my question, I added the meta

Comment: @Ilario .. i posted an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

The problem was given by the `z-index` property that had been given to the image,

removing the `z-index`, problem disappeared

Answer (score 1):

have you tried removing the **target-densityDpi** .. it is now deprecated and removed from webkit:

http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/119527

so try any of the following.. this just declares **target-density**:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no; target-density=device-dpi;" />
```

and this, with no **target-density**:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
```

or this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

since **target-densityDpi** is removed.. try any of the above viewport meta tags

Comment: thanks for your reply, I tried to change the meta as you suggested but it does not change anything..

Comment: i have a galaxy s3 also .. what is the app or website that you are seeing this on?

Comment: maybe I'll say something stupid, but I'm noticing that the problem of poor resolution is only noticeable when in the data-role "content" there is a <ul>

Comment: what are you using to develop your app for android? are you using jQuery mobile?

Comment: do you have the markup for that ul and what css is associated with it